# Bind additonal elements In ICollection<Model> Without breaking EF EDMX

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-6

I have trouble binding data into a `DataGrid` with `MVVM` approach. Might be silly but I'm stuck.


**I have an EF6 table `EFTable` which looks something like this**

```
namespace Database.Models
{    
    [Table(Name = "EFTable")]
    public class EFTable
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int Col1 { get; set; }

        public int Col2 { get; set; }

        .................
        ...................

    }
}
```

**In my ViewModel I have**

```
 public ICollection<EFTable> EFTableToBindWithDataGrid
 {
     get
     {
         return efTable;
     }
     set
     {
         efTable = value;

         RaisePropertyChanged("EFTableToBindWithDataGrid");
     }
 }
```

**Finally in my View(xaml) I have a DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid   ColumnWidth="*"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{ Binding Path=EFTableToBindWithDataGrid,Mode=OneWay}" >    
    <DataGrid.Columns>    
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Col1}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Binding="{Binding Col2}" />
        <!--................-->
         <!--#####HERE-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ColNotInEFTable" Binding="{Binding ColNotInEFTable}" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>   
</DataGrid>
```

**Let me state my problem**

1. I need to bind computed value `ColNotInEFTable`  but they are not in `EFTableToBindWithDataGrid`( as `EFTable`  does not have `ColNotInEFTable` field)
2. Is there are any alternative ways to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `computed values CGST and SGST but they are not in AddedInvoiceProducts`. don't you think that those code should be a part of [MCVE]?

Comment: it was just an example.

Comment: ok, great. to answer your question ("Is there are any alternative ways to resolve this issue?"): YES

Comment: I have updated the question with a generic example

Answer (score 2):

Create a `ViewModel` from your `Model`.

```
public class ViewModelInvoiceProduct : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   //only the properties in Model that you want to show in DataGrid

   //your additional property
   private int _CGST;
   public int CGST
    {
        get
        {
            return _CGST;
        }
        set
        {
            _CGST = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CGST");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**VIEWMODEL** : and bind a `AddedInvoiceProductsViewModel` to your `DataGrid`

```
public ICollection<ViewModelInvoiceProduct> AddedInvoiceProductsViewModel {get;set;}

public ICollection<InvoiceProducts> AddedInvoiceProducts
    {
        get
        {
            return invoiceProducts;
        }
        set
        {
            invoiceProducts = value;
            //the idea to populate AddedInvoiceProductsViewModel
            foreach(var invoice in invoiceProducts)
            {
                var temp = new ViewModelInvoiceProduct();
                temp.XXX = invoice.XXX;
                temp.CGST = 1 + 2;
                AddedInvoiceProductsViewModel.Add(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: InvoiceProducts, the idea is create a list ViewModel cloned from Model

Answer (score 1):

1. You can extend your InvoiceProducts class: mark it as partial class and add new properties to the partial class placed to a new file InvoiceProductsExtended.cs
2. Also You can replace InvoiceProducts with a new class (wrapper or inheritor) and bind to it
3. Use binding converter for calculating new values from original properties

Comment: Does this approach lead to any problem when I Update my Database through `dataContext.saveChanges()` method?

Comment: New calculating properties are not mapped in EF EDMX file (mapping). I think dataContext.saveChanges() should work fine

Comment: Thank you, I would check that too